# R - anyway to speed up dbWriteTable?

Tags: r, sql-server, r-dbi

I am working with a dataframe c. 700k rows and 400 columns which I'm uploading to Microsoft SQL Server. I'm currently using the code:

```
dbWriteTable(conn = con, 
                     name = "table_test", 
                     value = x,
                     row.names = FALSE
                     )
```

from the library `library(odbc)` and `con` is my connection made by using the function `dbConnect`

The code does run, but it takes a few hours. Is there any faster way I can do this?

Comment: I've been using `DBI` and `odbc` to insert 2M+ row data (at least weekly) for a few years now, and using `dbWriteTable` is (as you have found) just too slow, so I use the command-line tool `bcp` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15). It has some *issues*; namely, it is brain-dead about quoted values, ignoring the CSV standard (RFC-4180) for embedded quotes, and it does not differentiate between `""` (empty string) and null. There is no good tool, you'll need to handle these problems manually.

Comment: @r2evans bcp.exe is a lost cause. Since SQL Server 2017 `BULK INSERT` can work with RFC 4180 files. (Only took twelve years.)

Comment: It is informative, then, to say that the server I can access (but do not administer) is 2016 (over 4y old). And it is depressing (to me). And they keep the compatibility level as 120 (instead of 130+ that adds `openjson` and similar good-to-have).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning : `BULK INSERT` sounds great, assuming you have access to an Azure blob or a filesystem (e.g., cifs) accessible by both the user and the server (I'm not going to open up a windows share on my computer in order to upload to the server: mostly (but not entirely) because CIFS over SSH is a nightmare, thanks microsoft. It's a nice notion, but it's hardly a solution for most users.